# Workflow guards, change error code from 400 to 403

Tags: symfony, workflow

Do you know if it's possible to change the error code of the workflow guard in symfony?
Right now, it returns a code 400. But I would like to return a code 403.

Following this method: https://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow.html#blocking-transitions

I can use a listener to throw the error I want, but if I can achieve it easily, juste by yaml configuration, it would be better.

Thank you